# VMWare 12.5 doesn't like my gcc-6 under Mint

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-16.04, vmware-workstation

I'm spending way too muhc time on trying to figure this out, so I decided to ask you guys for a little help.

I downloaded VMWare Workstation 12.5.5 on kernel 4.10.8 (Linux Mint 18.1).

A popup show up saying I don't have gcc >= 6.2.0.

After trying to compile it I realised there's a version hosted on a ppa:

> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial
> main
>
> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt install gcc-6

I relaunch vmware and I still get this error. Entering the path manually to /usr/bin/gcc-6 doesn't work either. /usr/bin/gcc-6 -v gives me `gcc version 6.2.0 20160901 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~16.04)`

How can I run VMware on my machine? Thanks! :D